# Why do my tires seem to be jumping?

Tags: tire, pedals

I bike for work and I've taken a few days off for the holidays. It's been very cold and rainy and Ive tried to keep my bike covered. I hopped on my bike after about a week and a half of disuse, and I began pedaling. With each pedal rotation it seemed like I was going over a small speed bump with my front tire. I tried pedaling faster and slower but the bumping sped and slowed down respectively. Also whenever I used my handbrake I'd smell this weird almost burning smell.

Comment: Simple, quick check:  pick up the front of the bike and spin the front wheel.  Watch for the wheel/tire hitting anything, or anything that doesn't look right as the wheel turns - for example, the rim or tire moves in and out or back and forth.

Comment: Almost certainly the tire is not properly seated on the rim.  The smell is from the tire rubbing the brake pad where it bulges out from the rim.

Answer (score 10):

Burning smell?  **Stop riding the bike immediately!**

Inspect your bike closely and identify what is rubbing.  I'd suspect the brake pads, or possibly a tyre is rubbing on a part of the frame.

Another cause that exacerbates a burning smell is animal urine on the brakes.  Leaving your bike outside means it could be used as a toilet target.

---

Also look closely at your front tyre.  Spin the wheel and see if there is a flat spot in the tyre, or if the rim is damaged.  Also look for rocks/pebbles stuck in the tread.   Check your tyre pressures too - if they're low that won't help.

I wonder if your bike has been out in the super cold for a bit longer than you realise.  Even leaving it covered, the bike will deteriorate fast.  Consider parking the bike inside a house or garage instead.   Under a porch or carport roof is better than out in the open.

Comment: Another possibility is the tire has developed a bulge from side wall damage. If the brake pads started rubbing the tire sidewall (i.e., burning rubber smell), and the sidewall became compromised, a bulge could have formed resulting in the bumping reported by the OP.